# Flipping an image vertically in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

Examples on the Internet claim that simply setting scaleX="-1" will flip an image in Flex.

But when I do this, the image doesn't seem to render at all.

What's going on? How can I troubleshoot the issue? I've tried placing it in a Canvas and a VBox, same result. 
(Note - the image is rather large, 5600x2100 or so.)

Comment: `scaleX` should definitely work, please show a source code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why scaleX isn't working, but I came up with a solution:

```
        var flipVerticalMatrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
        flipVerticalMatrix.scale(1, -1);
        flipVerticalMatrix.translate(0, bm.height);

        bitmap = new Bitmap(new BitmapData(bm.width, bm.height, false, 0x00AA00));
        bitmap.bitmapData.draw(bm, flipVerticalMatrix);
```

Would still be interested in any info as to why scaleX didn't work.

Comment: Just so you know, you saved me from a weird Flash crash I kept getting from trying to rotate a displayObject for 180 degrees, and the scale idea is working very neatly. Thanks a lot